# Configure URL for domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app, and now I'm going to deploy it, but before I need to solve the issue I faced.

Some of my controller methods and links use `object_url` method.

And it returns `http://localhost:3000/...`

Of course, after deployment that won't work.

How I can point Rails, that it should work as `http://domain.com/...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to care about it. Rails will handle this automatically. It recognizes user request and takes the domain name from it. Just deploy it. Set the DNS and you will see.